# django - how to get value of key-value queryset from values()

Tags: python, django

I am stuck not knowing how to do this. i am using `values()` method to get specific column from db but i dont know how to get the value of that column in queryset, i am getting after `values()` something like this:

```
[columnname: value]
```

I want to get only the value. I think, in views.py i can get the value with `object['column']`, but how do i get the value in template in django?

or what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) in Django templates:

```
{{ object.column }}
```

> Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable
>   name signifies a lookup. Specifically, when the template system
>   encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups,
>   in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup. Example: foo["bar"]
> - Attribute lookup. Example: foo.bar
> - List-index lookup. Example: foo[bar]

Comment: it says: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores. fieldname in my model starts with _fieldname. is that bad?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693888/accessing-dict-elements-with-leading-underscores-in-django-templates. It'll help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

{{ object.column }} is the template syntax.