# django template forloop for _key

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, django-templates, iteration

I have the json value in my django template and I need to loop for every value inside it.

```
{
    "hits": [
       {
        "_index": "catalog",
        "_type": "mobiles",
        "_id": "2e4d3356-95eb-4cc2-b4be-f75baa55248f",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "name": "Apple iPhone 5S 16GB Space Grey",
            "product_score": "109",
            "product_rating": {
                "avg": "5",
                "count": "1"
            }
        }
       }
   ]
}
```

**How should I iterate inside "_source"?**

This code doesn't work:

```
{% for i in hits.items %}
<div>{{i}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

*The primary doubt is how to loop inside "_(underscore)" element*

Comment: This is not a valid json. You forgot an opening bracket

Comment: @GuillaumeThomas I have just posted a small part. The json that I actually have is valid. It is huge.

Comment: I understand but there is still a missing opening bracket before the "_index". This is a bit misleading

Comment: yes, right...I will update it now.

Comment: Potential duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693888/accessing-dict-elements-with-leading-underscores-in-django-templates

Comment: Nope... I know how to get a single value. I need to know how to loop inside that.