# django languange change takes effect only after reload

Tags: django, django-templates, django-i18n

In my app I can change the language by the following:

```
from django.utils.translation import LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY
# LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY is "_language"
...
def my_view(request, my_lang=en):
    request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = my_lang
    ...
    context = {"mysession": session}
    return render(request, "mytemplate.html", context)
```

This works mostly as expected. However, the direct response of this view renders still in the previous language despite the session variable is set correctly. In other words the following template gives imho contradictory output:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<b>Debug:</b>
current_language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}
session_variable: {{mysession|get:"_language"}}
```

Note that, to access the attribute `_language` beginning with an underscore I have to use a custom filter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694031/333403).

Django-Output:

> Debug: current_language: en sessionvariable: de

All `{% trans ... }` statements are handled to the (outdated) content of `LANGUAGE_CODE`, which is annoying. After changing the language the uses expects an immediate effect. If I refresh the page or load a different view, then the new language is used correctly.

1. Do I understand something wrong?
2. How can I achieve that the current_language is set correctly in the immediate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the language code in the session, but you didn't actually [activate the new language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language) in the view.

```
from django.utils import translation
...
translation.activate(my_lang)
```